# How to warn if a property is accessed without being initialized, by adding an attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'd like some technique to automatically replace the following code:

```
[WarnIfGetButUninitialized]
public int MyProperty {get; set; }
```

With this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Property which warns you if its value is fetched before it has been specifically instantiated.
/// </summary>
private bool backingFieldIsPopulated = false;
private int backingField;
public int MyProperty { 
    get
    {
        if (backingFieldIsPopulated == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: cannot fetch property before it has been initialized properly.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        return backingField;
    }
    set { 
        backingField = value;
        backingFieldIsPopulated = true;
    }
}
```

I'd prefer a solution that works at compile time, as reflection is slow.

I am aware that Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) will do this (e.g. PostSharp and CciSharp) but I'd be interested if there is any other method to achieve this.

**Update**

See [How to use PostSharp to warn if a property is accessed before it has been initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033577/how-to-use-postsharp-to-warn-if-a-property-is-accessed-before-it-has-been-initia) which has a link to some sample code that demonstrates the technique using PostSharp.

Comment: I'd say your easiest bet is using PostSharp or Unity IoC which can do limited AOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Gael Fraiteur on the PostSharp forum (thanks Gael!):

> You have to use a LocationInterceptionAspect that implements
>   IInstanceScopedAspect. The field 'backingFieldIsPopulated' becomes a
>   field of the aspect.
>
> You can find inspiration in this example:
>
> http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Content.aspx/PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/d3631074-e131-467e-947b-d99f348eb40d.htm

Answer (score 2):

Attributes simply add meta data to classes and class members - by themselves they do nothing.

The operations done on decorated members are done through reflection - there is some support for that in some of the existing tooling, but there will be no such support for custom attributes.

In short - you can't have an attribute checked at compile time if the compiler does not already have support for it.

You can, however, create your own [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) to make such code easier to write and create.

Comment: I can do this with any Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) utility, such as PostSharp or CciSharp. The question is - how?

Comment: @Gravitas - Yes, though this is an _extra_ step _before_ compilation (and in my experience, PostSharp is rather slow).

Comment: I assume you mean slightly slower at compile time (but the same at runtime). Doesn't it inject IL directly into the compiled assembly, so the net result is the same as if you coded it up yourself?

Comment: @Gravitas - _much_ slower during compile time. It does indeed do IL weaving - personally, I find that the result obscures what will actually be produced.

Comment: AOP is only suitable for cross cutting concerns, e.g. adding logging on an exception. The whole point is to obscure the boiler plate code, as it makes the code a lot cleaner. However, I do agree that it can be misused (like anything in C#, I guess).

Comment: Postsharp's post-compile speed has increased dramatically in recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

T4 templates can be used for code generation. Have not implemented my self, but T4 templates are used for code generation in C#. More info from scott hanselman

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Comment: I am currently using T4. However, the T4 editor is slightly lacking compared to the one provided by Visual Studio / ReSharper (why can't T4 work with the built in editor in Visual Studio?).

Answer (score 0):

Only some attributes are checked through compilation.
ObsoleteAttribute and ConditionalAttribute are two of them.
Using Resharper, you can get such warnings. I dont know any other tool that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a implementation similar to .NET's Lazy, but this would require a little more wordiness when using the property.  Something like this non-thread safe example:

```
public class WarnIfGetButUninitialized<T>
{
    T _property;
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if(_property == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: cannot fetch property before it has been initialized properly.\n");
                return default(T);
            }
            return _property;
        }
        set { _property = value; }
    }
}
```