# How to use PostSharp to warn if a property is accessed before it has been initialized?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, postsharp

How would I use PostSharp to replace this:

```
[WarnIfGetButUninitialized]
public int MyProperty {get; set; }
```

With this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Property which warns you if its value is fetched before it has been specifically instantiated.
/// </summary>
private bool backingFieldIsPopulated = false;
private int backingField;
public int MyProperty { 
    get
    {
        if (backingFieldIsPopulated == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: cannot fetch property before it has been initialized properly.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        return backingField;
    }
    set { 
        backingField = value;
        backingFieldIsPopulated = true;
    }
}
```

**Update**

I should also add that this is a good method to increase code reliability. In a project with 20,000 lines, its nice to know that everything is initialized properly before its used. I intend to use this for the Debug build, and remove it in the Release build, because 
I don't want to slow the end release down unnecessarily.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to warn if a property is accessed without being initialized, by adding an attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033385/how-to-warn-if-a-property-is-accessed-without-being-initialized-by-adding-an-at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Gael Fraiteur on the PostSharp forum (thanks Gael!):

> You have to use a LocationInterceptionAspect that implements
>   IInstanceScopedAspect. The field 'backingFieldIsPopulated' becomes a
>   field of the aspect.
>
> You can find inspiration in this example:
>
> http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Content.aspx/PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/d3631074-e131-467e-947b-d99f348eb40d.htm

Comment: Another example of dealing with Properties: see http://www.sharpcrafters.com/forum/Topic3876-19-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about your constructor initializes it properly and then you don't have to worry about it?

Comment: Sure, if you're working on a 100 line project. If you're working on a 50,000 line project, this sort of technique during the development phase catches errors that might slip through the net due to human error. This technique is also good for checking legacy code. Its one small technique in a basket that helps to produce robust, enterprise level code.